# Migrating to a newer version of PHP

Tags: php, migration

I notice that a couple of weeks ago PHP 5.3 reached release candidate stage (woo!), but then seeing the list of already-deprecated functions finally being removed, that got me thinking about whether it would break any of my old code.

Short of doing a suck-it-and-see test (installing on a test server and trying it out), are there any sort of migration tools which can analyse your code to highlight issues? For example, if some scripts use the `ereg_*` functions.

Comment: What version are you currently running?

Comment: 5.2.4, though that shouldn't matter?

Comment: Well I can think of issues if you go from 5.1 -> 5.3 that won't be there if you go from 5.2 -> 5.3. Of coruse current and new versions are both relevant.

Comment: In the article here: http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/UPGRADING?view=markup&pathrev=PHP_5_3 I don't see mention of removed functions.  Can you link to where you saw that?

Comment: I know of a few things that get deprecated in 5.3 but not removed until 6.

Comment: well, even still... such a tool (should it exist) would be able to give warnings about deprecated functions too, I'd suppose.

Comment: I think that you should be able to turn on warnings somewhere and get info about deprecated functions.  I can look it up if you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

One technique you could use is to take the list of deprecated functions that is being removed and grep for them.  A little shell scripting fu goes a long way for things like this.

Let's suppose you have a file deprecated.txt with deprecated function names one per line:

```
for func in `cat deprecated.txt`
do
  grep -R $func /path/to/src
done
```

That will tell you all the instances of the deprecated functions you're using.

Comment: Rather than re-grep in a loop, it's probably more efficient to create a statement like:
egrep -R '(dep_func_1|dep_func_2|etc...)' /path/to/src

Another option would be to generate an xdebug trace file, which will include the names of called functions -- but it'd be hard to get 100% code coverage

Comment: Of course that would be more efficient, but it's a bit harder to write an easy-to-read shell script that reads dep_func_1, dep_func_2, etc. from a file and does the grep.  I did it for ease of readability, not for speed. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Nothing beats installing on a test server and running your unit tests.  You do have unit tests, right? ;)

Comment: Unit tests are FTW, but I think he explicitly said he wants a heuristic that doesn't involve a test server. :-)

Comment: yeah sorry for the arbitrary caveat, but i was wondering if there was anything else besides that. Also, there's some third-party software for which I don't have any unit tests.