# is there any way to find php application is compatible with particular version or not

Tags: php, migration

I have one big php application running on php 4 but I want to move this application on php 5.2 but I am not sure whether it's all functionally work on it or not as I don't want to test full application again. So I want to know is there a way to find out compatibility of application with php versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating to a newer version of PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732207/migrating-to-a-newer-version-of-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP5 come with major changes, I don't think there's such an automated way to check compatibility out there..

You'll have to check all files manualy. use batch file text seach (and replace?) tools to look for functions, classes etc.

here's your [guide to start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to test it. You can at least use the [PHP changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.14) as a bit of a checklist to see if any code in application is affected.

PHP 4 to PHP 5 was a pretty huge leap; it's probably a safe bet your app was affected even before you go through testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use online tool for checking [syntax compatibility](http://www.meandeviation.com/tutorials/learnphp/php-syntax-check/v4/syntax-check.php) of your code php 4 and php 5.2,5.3. For manual checking read [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php) .